# Material-UI TexField Select - different display when expanded

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

How would I show for example `01` in `MenuItem` when `TextField` is collapsed and `01 - this is first element` when it's expanded on Material-UI's TextField select component?

Comment: Please add more code or at least where you are stuck if you have tried something.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Though the approach in Domino987's answer will work, Material-UI provides the [`renderValue` prop](https://material-ui.com/api/select/#props) on `Select` for this purpose. If you provide a function in the `renderValue` prop, that function will be provided the selected value as an argument and then whatever the function returns is what will be displayed in the collapsed view. Below is an example based on one of the `TextField` demos. In my example, only the currency symbol is displayed in the collapsed view, but in the expanded view it shows the symbol followed by the text abbreviation for the currency in parentheses.

```
import React from "react";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import MenuItem from "@material-ui/core/MenuItem";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  container: {
    display: "flex",
    flexWrap: "wrap"
  },
  textField: {
    marginLeft: theme.spacing(1),
    marginRight: theme.spacing(1),
    width: 200
  },
  dense: {
    marginTop: 19
  },
  menu: {
    width: 200
  }
}));

const currencies = [
  {
    value: "USD",
    label: "$"
  },
  {
    value: "EUR",
    label: "€"
  },
  {
    value: "BTC",
    label: "฿"
  },
  {
    value: "JPY",
    label: "¥"
  }
];

export default function TextFields() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [values, setValues] = React.useState({
    currency: currencies[0]
  });

  const handleChange = name => event => {
    setValues({ ...values, [name]: event.target.value });
  };

  return (
    <form className={classes.container} noValidate autoComplete="off">
      <TextField
        id="standard-select-currency"
        select
        label="Select"
        className={classes.textField}
        value={values.currency}
        onChange={handleChange("currency")}
        SelectProps={{
          MenuProps: {
            className: classes.menu
          },
          renderValue: option => option.label
        }}
        helperText="Please select your currency"
        margin="normal"
      >
        {currencies.map(option => (
          <MenuItem key={option.value} value={option}>
            {option.label} ({option.value})
          </MenuItem>
        ))}
      </TextField>
    </form>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit Select renderValue]

Answer (score 3):

You can make it controlled and change the menu content according to that open state like this:

```
<Select
  open={open}
  onClose={handleClose}
  onOpen={handleOpen}
  value={selectedItem}
  onChange={handleChange}
  inputProps={{
    name: 'selectedItem',
  }}
  >
  <MenuItem value={0}>{open? 1 - this is first element : 01}</MenuItem>
  <MenuItem value={1}>{open? 2 - this is second element : 02}</MenuItem>
  <MenuItem value={2}>{open? 3 - this is third element : 03}</MenuItem>   
</Select>
```